# Get attributes for all values in a query sqlalchemy

Tags: python, database, flask-sqlalchemy

My database model is below: Users -->

```
class Users(db.Model):
   __tablename__ = 'users'
   id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
   name = db.Column(db.String(length=100), nullable=False, unique=False)
   email = db.Column(db.String(length=30), nullable=False, unique=True)
   password_hash = db.Column(db.String(length=30),nullable=False,unique=False)
   isCorrect= db.Column(db.Boolean(),nullable=False, unique=False)
```

I'm trying to query specifically all values of isCorrect for True and access the name **and** email of the query. Here is my query below:

```
check = Users.query.filter_by(isCorrect=True)
```

How can I add an additional method at the end of my query to get the name and email values?

I tried looping through the query as shown below:

```
for name in (Users.query.filter_by(isCorrect=True).all()):
   names = list(Users.query.filter_by(isTutor=True).first())
```

However, I got this error:

```
TypeError: 'Users' object is not iterable
```

I also tried converting the query into a list, but I got the same error.

How can a list of all the attributes of a single query in SQLACHEMY (specifically flask extension)?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

[all()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.all) returns the results of the query as a Python `list`.

```
# Get all users whose isCorrect column is True
for user in Users.query.filter_by(isCorrect=True).all():
    # user is an instance of your Users class
    print(user.name)
    print(user.email)
    print(user.isCorrect)
```